# JFileChooser Opening twice

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I'm trying to create a app where I need a file chooser after a I click a certain button. Problem is when I do so, after I select the file i want or click cancel, the JFileChooser opens again. I've been looking through some pages and i can't seem to find a solution. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```java
FileInputStream imatgeUp = null;
File arxiu = null;
if (comanda.equals("cercaImatge")) {
    JFileChooser pickPic = new JFileChooser();
    pickPic.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Archivos de imagen", "jpg", "jpeg", "png"));
    //int opcion = pickPic.showOpenDialog(addCar);

    if (pickPic.showOpenDialog(addCar) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        String ruta = pickPic.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
        try {
            arxiu = new File(ruta);
            imatgeUp = new FileInputStream(arxiu);
            Icon imatgeMostra = new ImageIcon(ruta);
            imatgeEscollida.setIcon(imatgeMostra);
            imatgeEscollida.setBounds(400, 250, 190, 122);
            addCar.add(imatgeEscollida);
                                                                        
            UploadImage.upImage(con, imatgeUp);
                                    
            frame.revalidate();
            frame.repaint();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing a message just before calling `showOpenDialog(...)` to ensure that your code is not being called twice?

Comment: @Pieter12345 I had not tried that, turned out I had 2 listeners for the same button, thanks a lot!